# Como Precificar um projeto Freelancer

Tags: api, back-end, job

Estou negociando os detalhes de um projeto, cujo me foi proposto pra desenvolver uma API de carros para uma aplicação mobile, terei que fazer um gerenciamento desses carros (CRUD, banco de dados...) E conectar esses dados relacionado a carros com a api do google maps. Tenho experiência em desenvolvimento de API'S , assim como confiança que consigo fazer oque é necessário

Apesar desse conhecimento, não tenho experiência com freelancer e estou na fase onde o cliente esta me perguntando sobre meu preço, me encontro com essa dúvida, como proceder?

Comment: Boas-vindas João. O site Stack Overflow em Português não e um site de serviços ou helpdesk. Recomendo que faça o [tour], leia o [help] e o [escopo](/help/on-topic). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.